# MYSQL versions that install with MAMP or XMAPP for Windows are old

Tags: mysql, xampp, mamp

I download MAMP for Windows 10 or XMAPP and I get an older version of MYSQL installed  than the one listed in the data sheet.  I need 5.6 and I keep getting 5.5.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

MAMP by default has the 6.5.34 version of MySQL (as specified [here](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)) and XAMMP doesn't even have MySQL but MariaDB version 10.1.32 (as stated [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)) so how did you get the 5.* version?

Comment: Google search and downloaded from their site.